# Is there any way to make a collider collide only with a specific GameObject without using layers?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

Basicly I have a GameObject with BoxCollider attached to it and I want it to collide only with one specific BoxCollider, ignoring all other collisions. Is there any way to do that without using layers? I want to avoid using layers because I need that system to be as flexible as its possible.

I can technicly use `Physics.IgnoreCollision` but it will drastically lower game performance and I want to avoid it.

Comment: Well you could use the collider matrix

Comment: This is the first time I’ve heard that IgnoreCollision harm performance. Do you have a source? It was my understanding that it was no more (minuscule) performance degrading than using layers?

Comment: In my case it will be necessary to ignore huge amount of collisions, so that's why it will harm performance in my project.

Answer (score -1):

Although it is a 'trick' method, there is a way to add a specific class component only to a specific collider that you want to collide, and then, when processing it in another place, there is a way to determine the class.

Hope this helps.